¿Comó puedo limitar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador?
Estoy aprendiendo sobre flutter, y tengo el siguiente codigo
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'centro/centro.dart';
import 'lado_derecho/lado_derecho.dart';
import 'lado_izquierdo/lado_izquierdo.dart';
import 'navbar/navbar.dart';

class DashboardPrincipal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: NavBarPrincipal(),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 1920,
                minHeight: 1080,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    LadoIzquierdoPrincipal(),
                    CentroPrincipal(),
                    const LadoDerechoPrincipal(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Lo que necesito es que si el usuario quiere hacer la ventana del navegador mas pequeña de 1920 * 1080 no pueda, estuve buscando como hacerlo y se supone que esta es la forma deberia de funcionar, pero a la hora de hacer pruebas si me deja hacerla mas pequeña

Cuando hablás del navegador, suena a que estás trabajando con flutter web. ¿Es así o te estabas refiriendo a tu aplicación móvil?

Estoy trabajando en flutter web
